# speechbubble tooltip using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, web, css

I want to create a Speech-Bubble tooltip using css3 or jquery for one of my websites.How can develop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/.../stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

http://bassistance.de/jquery.../jquery-plugin-tooltip/

http://www.dreamcss.com/.../12-jquery-tooltip-for-web-developer.html

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/ (I use this)